# Handle typing with data spread between main query and fragment reference in abstracted React components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, relayjs, react-relay

Based on the [example of Relay](https://relay.dev/docs/tutorial/arrays-lists/), it seems trivial to implement a list that read the data from the main query and extract the fragment data from the story ref.

**Relay example**
[image]

However, if we add a level of abstraction and need to deal with typing, it's a different story.
Here is my example:

```
export default function Newsfeed({}) {
  const data = useLazyLoadQuery<NewsfeedQueryType>(NewsfeedQuery, {});
  const stories = data.topStories;
  return (
    <div className="newsfeed">
      <StoryList stories={stories} />
    </div>
  );
}

// The way I found is to extract the node type myself and later cast it to StoryFragment$key, which works but I feel like it's a trick
type StoryNode = NewsfeedQuery$data['topStories'][0]

function StoryList(stories: StoryNode[]) { // <<< HERE I'm using the extracted StoryNode to access the data from the main query, however my Story component expect a StoryFragment$key. Which seems accepted, as an implicit cast occurs, the compiler doesn't complain.
  return (
    <>
      {stories.map(story => (
        <Story
          key={story.id} // <<<<< HERE: I'd like to use data from the main query and not from the fragment
          storyRef={story} // <<< HERE: Looks like an implicit cast occurs to StoryFragment$key
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}

function Story(storyRef: StoryFragment$key) {
  // Use fragment expect the generate type StoryFragment$key
  const story = useFragment(StoryFragment, storyRef)
  ...
}
```

The way I found is to extract the node type myself and later cast it to StoryFragment$key, which works, but I feel like it's a trick. Especially in a real case where usually the data looks more like:

```
topStories {
  edges {
     node {
       id
       ...StoryFragment
     }
  }
}
```

In that case we ends with:

```
type TopStories = NonNullable<NewsfeedQuery$data['topStories']>;
type StoryEdge = NonNullable<TopStories['edges']>[0];
type StoryNode = NonNullable<StoryEdge>['node'];
```

Which is probably ok, however the cast to the fragment ref bother me, and I feel like something is not right.

What would be the optimal way to handle the typing properly in that case?